# C# Visualization - What are the options?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, visualization

I found [processing library](http://processing.org/) which is java based and was thinking if there is any C# implementation or similar project that allows this. I know there is already silverlight for .NET but is there any other option for desktop based visualization for C# ?

If i want to create visualization using C# (similar to that of processing), what are my available options ? How you'll proceed in case of visualization with C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing has a *very* simple interface; I'm not aware of anything on that level for C#. However, if you're looking to make some fancy graphics, [have a look at XNA](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/).

XNA runs on Windows and the XBOX, has a LOT of excellent tutorials and sample projects available, and removes the complexities of dealing with OpenGL or DirectX without sacrificing power. I'm using XNA to render volume representations of light waves propogating through waveguides and freespace (a physics simulator, not a game) and it works incredibly well. It's slightly more complicated than Processing, but very easy to get up and running with.

Comment: I think XNA will be too heavy for presentation based projects. But definitely have to take a look if it's better than handling opengl/directx stuff.

Comment: It's definitely more complex than Processing, but if you want to get into 3D it's the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

SilverLight is not really what your are looking for, I think you should rather consider OpenGL or DirectX (which includes DirectShow, DirectSound, DirectVideo and so on...).

Comment: sorry depending really on what you want to do, WPF could actually work as well and is much higher level than raw OpenGL or DirectX.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is a slimmed down version of wpf.  I would suggest wpf over silverlight if this is a desktop app.